# Angular 6 : ng build --aot

Tags: angular, visual-studio, build, aot

When I upgrade to angular 6 I recieve this error in visual studio.
How to fix it?
in this line :
    
Look here:
[ng build --aot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EjQ0R.jpg)

Comment: Welcome! I think your best bet is to do a web search on 'MSB3073'. You will likely find good information for this error code.

Answer (score 0):

In your `result.component.ts` you set your property `quizService` as `private` but you are trying to use it in your `result.component.html`.

so you have 2 options:

1- change declaration of `quizService` as  `public` instead of `private`.
2- create an observable for what you are trying to use in that html (or a function) and use it there instead of calling the service directly in your html.

By the way, if you scroll up in your Output console you will see the real errors and file names that are causing aot build to fail.